# JQuery load event not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, onload-event

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Jquery load event not working</title> 
   <style>
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .big {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .blue {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body> 
 
<div class="big"></div>
 
<script>
$( "div" ).load(function() {
  $( this ).switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery **load** event not working. You can check above code, wanted change of class from big to blue with background-color changing to #00f along with width and height of div

Comment: You dont need load() event, just type `$( this ).switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );`. Since javascript is in the end of the code

Comment: Sorry, `$( 'div' ).switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );`, not `$( this ).switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // $("div") div is ready

});
```

When document ready means all elements within the DOM are ready to be used.

Check [link for more info.](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/div-readyfunction-is-this-possible/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( 'div' ).switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .big {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .blue {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="big"></div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p7skoay/)**

Comment: thanks, just tell one thing, we used  $( 'div' ).switchClass(); why div ??

Comment: @Manish Because we are applying swichclass to div. what will it consider this means? If you apply on click like https://jsfiddle.net/4p7skoay/1/ then it will consider this as div. because you have written code on div click.

Comment: Okay, so we don't have to use load event, like for click ?

Comment: @Manish no man as you write script after the element then no need to write load event. Else you should write `$(document).ready(function(){` I will recommend to use it.

Comment: Thanks @ketan brother

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the method with the `div` element, no need to use `.load()`

```
$("div").switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
```

Note: As you have specified the script after the element, no need of document-ready handler.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.big {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="big"></div>

<script>
$("div").switchClass("big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the jQuery code inside .ready() like below :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "div" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    });
});
</script>
```

Also you used .load instead of .click on the 'div' you wanted to add animation.